# How to upgrade conda version via anaconda prompt?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, command-prompt

I'm using conda to install a couple of packages, and it warns me with:

```
==> WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. <==
  current version: 4.7.10
  latest version: 4.10.1

Please update conda by running

    $ conda update -n base -c defaults conda
```

My question is that how can I upgrade to a specific version instead of a latest version, for example conda version 4.9.2?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pretty simple to do so! Use these commands without "<<  >>"

```
conda update conda
conda install anaconda=<<VersionNumber>>
```

Hope this solves your problems.
More info at [Anaconda Documentation](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/update-version/)

Comment: I am facing the same problem except in my case it says: latest version: 22.11.1 . Did the version increase so rapidly from 4 to 22? or is it my environment problem?

Comment: @qqqqq conda switched to calendar versioning, 4.15 was folowed by 22 as in 2022.

Answer (score 2):

```
conda update -n base -c defaults conda
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done


==> WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. <==
  current version: 4.10.3
  latest version: 23.3.1

Please update conda by running

    $ conda update -n base -c defaults conda



# All requested packages already installed.

(base) andrew@debianbuster:~$ conda update conda
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done


==> WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. <==
  current version: 4.10.3
  latest version: 23.3.1

Please update conda by running

    $ conda update -n base -c defaults conda



# All requested packages already installed.

(base) andrew@debianbuster:~$ conda install anaconda=23.3.1
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - anaconda=23.3.1

Current channels:

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error and here is what worked

```
conda install conda=XX.X.X
```

or as earlier addressed, if it is anaconda, the exact version that you want. Hope it works out.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).